# how to crawl like counts of comments on youtube video?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make corpus of comments on a certain video of youtube with selenium and BeautifulSoup. (I'm not trying to use Youtube Data api, because of the limit.)

and i almost did it but i could have got the result with only comments and ids...

i checked the space which contain the like counts info then i gave it into my code, it goes well anyway, but it does not retrieve the result, it gives me just nothing........ idk why......

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd 
import re
from collections import Counter
from konlpy.tag import Twitter

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\chrome\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4pxIxGdR_M&t=2s'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

html_source = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')

ids = soup.select('div#header-author > a > span')

comments = soup.select('div#content > yt-formatted-string#content-text')

likes = soup.select('ytd-comment-action-buttons-renderer#action-buttos > div#tollbar > span#vote-count-middle')

print('ID :', len(ids), 'Comments : ', len(comments), 'Likes : ' ,len(likes))
```

and 0 is just printed out... i have searched some of the ways to deal with it, but most of the answers were just to make me use the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wouldn't use BeautifulSoup for the extraction, just go with the built-in selenium tools, i.e.:

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]/span')
comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')
likes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="vote-count-middle"]')
```

This way you still can use `len()` due to them being iterables. You're also allowed to iterate over the variable `likes` and get the `.text` value to add them together:

```
total_likes = 0
for like in likes:
    total_likes += int(like.text)
```

To get this more pythonic you might as well go with a proper list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if entirely lines up with the requirement, but sites like socialbalde and moreofit can be combined to get a general overview and might be a better starting point of crawling, depending on your purpose. I personally found this to be useful.